# Tkinter - Fill a frame with a text widget, using place()

Tags: python, tkinter, text, widget

I am trying to fill a frame with a text widget and a scrollbar.

I cannot get the text to fill the frame and i have tried many different approaches and things i saw online.

The problem is i am using place(), while most of the tutorials and asnwers ar about grid().

This is my code:

```
 # --- frame 5 - SERIAL PRINTOUT ---

    frame5 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=5)
    frame5.place(relx = 0, rely = 0.4, relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.4)
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame5)
    scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    scrollbar.config(command=log.yview)
    log = tk.Text ( frame5, width=30, height=30, takefocus=0)
    log.pack()
    # attach text box to scrollbar
    log.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    # --- frame 5 - SERIAL PRINTOUT ---
```

Increasing width and height is not something i would like, because modifying the parent frame, will put me in a position to modify the text widget as well.
Isn't there a method, or setting to make it fill the parent frame automatically?

Comment: Why are you using `place`? `pack` is the more natural choice. Though, you appear to be using `pack` rather than `place` judging by the code `log.pack()`.

Comment: I am using place because it is my first time doing a GUI, and i do not want to waste so much time at the GUI itself. SInce my GUI has many frames, i didn't know how to place them all using pack(), having one under the other, instead with place() i am hardcoding their position.

Comment: If you want to fill the frame surely there is not much point in using `place()` as there won't be multiple widgets to juggle around. You should just use `.pack(side = LEFT)` and `.pack(side = RIGHT)`

Comment: @TheFluffDragon9 You mean log.pack(side = tk.LEFT, side = tk.RIGHT)? Will this work?

Comment: @TheFluffDragon9 or two different commands?

Comment: Try `log.pack(fill='both', expand=1)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes! Finally! If you want, make a proper answer instead of a comment so i can upvote and mark as the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `Text` widget to fill the available space inside its parent frame, you need to tell the pack layout manager via `fill` and `expand` options of `pack()`:

```
log.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
```